# Alert in tmux when a process completes

Tags: tmux

Can I set tmux to trigger an alert in a non-active window when a process completes?

For example: I start a long build process. I would like to be notified when it completes, not each time it prints a status.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the tmux window setting `visual-bell` for this. With `bell-action` you can then configure whether you want to see bells for the current window only, or for non-current window only (other). Personally I prefer the second, as you won't see noise generated by the shell, and you probably don't care about the notification if it's in the current window.

```
set-window-option -g visual-bell on
set-window-option -g bell-action other
```

When a process generates a bell, tmux will highlight the the title of the window that rings the bell as well as show a "Bell in window X" notification.

Then ring the bell at the end of the process. E.g.:

```
make; echo -e '\a'
```

(or `&&` `||` instead of `;` if you want to ring only on success or failure respectively)

Comment: `visual-bell on` means visual message only. If you do `visual-bell both`, then you both hear the bell and get a visual message.

Comment: I wonder if there is any options that waits for the user to accept a persistent notification before it disappears, like a popup alert window, possibly e.g. based on `command-prompt`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033091/how-to-have-tmux-prompt-me-for-the-status-left-text-to-display

Comment: Is it possible to not display message `Bell in window X`, just to trigger bell?

Answer (score 14):

There 3 solutions I know, none really ideal. You may put those commands in your `~/.tmux.conf` or just run them directly as Tmux command via Ctrl-B `:`.

1. Monitor and alert whenever the output changes (you may then redirect output somewhere else so that output changes only after the command is complete):

   ```
   :set -g visual-activity on
   :setw -g monitor-activity on
   ```
2. Monitor and alert whenever the output did *not* change for a while (30 seconds here):

   ```
   :set -g visual-silence on
   :setw -g monitor-silence 30
   ```
3. ([*deprecated* and someday replaced by a better option](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/372)) Monitor and alert whevener the output contains a string matching given pattern (and possibly run your command like `my-command; echo foobar`):

   ```
   :set -g visual-content on
   :setw -g monitor-content foo*bar
   ```
4. `$ some-command; tmux display-message "Task 1 done"`. However the message will only show for a short duration defined via `:set -g display-time 4000`.

If you keep the `visual-*` to `off` (default), it'll only highlight the name of the window in which the alert occurred without showing a global alert status message.

For details about each of these settings, see [tmux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/tmux.1.html)

### Updated (thanks for Steven Lu)

Comment: `monitor-content` appears to have been removed. But a more robust technique anyway might be something like `my-command; tmux display-message "We're done here!"`

Answer (score 10):

I use `zsh` for my shell, which has a feature called "Hook Functions" -- shell functions that execute on certain actions: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html.

It's likely other shells have a similar feature.

The hook function I use is `precmd`, which is executed each time the prompt is shown. ie, when a command has just finished running.

In my `.zshrc`:

```
precmd () {
  echo -n -e "\a"
}
```

This sends a bell to `tmux`, which causes it to highlight just the window that the command was running in.

If you are already focused on that `tmux` window, this does nothing because the bell is immediately cleared.

The benefit of this approach is that it does not trigger on *all* visual activity. It only triggers when a command completes.

Comment: The bell on the current window is just cleared with `set-option -g bell-action other` set in tmux, or else you get a bell on every command and have to wait until the bell finishes. If you ever use your shell without tmux, then there is also a bell on every command.

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap your running script with a && bash derivative which will call a tmux command to notify you.
using && means you will only get notified when the script exits with error code 0. if you want it to notify you anyway, just use ;

as for the tmux commands to wrap the script, have a look at those bunch, they should suffice
select-window
split-window -h 'exec echo...'
send-keys

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, people can also checkout the [tmux-notify](https://github.com/ChanderG/tmux-notify) plugin, created by ChanderG, which was designed for this purpose.

**Disclaimer:** I'm a contributor to this plugin. Feel free to check it out and open an issue/pull request or feature request if you find a bug or see something that is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Adding onto the answers from @wump and @psp940; I've found that the simplest way to be alerted any time a command completes is to put a bell in your `PS1`:

in `tmux.conf`

```
set-window-option -g visual-bell on
set-window-option -g bell-action other
```

In your `.bashrc`:

```bash
# ring bell every time a command completes
PS1+=$'\[\a\]'
```

I'm not sure whether the `+=` and `$''` are bash-isms, but the principle will work in any shell.

The surrounding `\[`+`\]` tell your shell that the characters between them are zero-width

Comment: Reverted the `export` edit: [as long as PS1 is set in .bashrc (recommended), it should not be exported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247627/460496)

Answer (score 2):

Building on @psp940's answer (where StackOverflow won't let me add a comment):

```
precmd () {
  echo -n -e "\a" >$TTY
}
```

If you're using powerlevel10k's instant prompt feature, redirecting the bell directly to the terminal avoids a warning about pre-init console output. See also [here](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/issues/1834#issuecomment-1092081444).

Answer (score 0):

there are two options:

```
set -g visual-activity on
setw -g monitor-activity on
```

have you tried setting them in your tmux.conf?

Comment: It's useful but seems to notify whenever the output changes and not only after the command completes.

Answer (score 0):

As a good workaround, you can use:
https://github.com/tcreech/tmux-notifications

You simply do:
$ command ; tmux-notify

You will get a nice notification in the status-bar (if enabled)

Comment: Just forgot, you can (need?) to pass a string to tmux-notify