# How to have tmux prompt me for the status-left text to display?

Tags: tmux

I want to change status bar left message to anything I type.
Just like when I press <kbd>Ctrl+B F</kbd> I have this prompt in status bar :

```
(find-window)
```

I'd like to press, say <kbd>Ctrl+B E</kbd> and have a prompt like :

```
(status-left)
```

Then on <kbd>Enter</kbd> the text I've typed would be assigned to status-left.

I *DON'T* want to have to call a shell script that would print the prompt in the shell window and print entered value (is that even possible?), I want the prompt to happen in the status bar itself.

How should I go with that? If i put in my `.tmux.conf` :

```
unbind e
bin e set status-left
```

It quite understandably prints *Empty value* message when I press <kbd>Ctrl+B E</kbd>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*command-prompt* is probably what you are looking for.

```
bind-key S command-prompt -p "New Status: " "set -g status-left '%1'"
```