# TMUX always beep on non active pane

Tags: tmux

I have tmux running with one window divided in 2 panes: left pane is my IRC client and right pane is a node.js bot.

My active pane is always IRC and I'd like to be notified about all activities on bot's pane, every log message etc.. What I mean is I'd like to have audible bell for highlights in IRC, like it normally is now, but also audible bells for every message my bot spits out.

Can I do this somehow? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert in tmux when a process completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755063/alert-in-tmux-when-a-process-completes)

Comment: The question might not be an exact duplicate, but [this answer to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39180062/5889131) exactly answers the question

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work for me, no (visual) bell at all. Also not sure about this but mine is a second buffer on same window, not a separate window.

Comment: They're called panes, not buffers. You're right that the answer talks about windows, not panes; I misread that. The terminal you're running tmux in needs to have the bell enabled. Does it? Try `echo -e '\a'` in the terminal without tmux running. You should hear a beep, or else figure out how to enable the bell in your specific terminal.